# Align ASP controls in table using CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

I'd like to align ASP labels and textBoxes, but I lost in CSS forest. The align of controls are bad. (Sorry my CSS code is bad.) I'd like to put the controls below each other in pairs (Label+TextBox). Help, please.

**aspx page:**

```
<asp:TableCell ID="tc0" runat="server" CssClass="searchTableLabelsCell">
    <asp:Label ID="lblrefNo" runat="server" Text="RefNo:" CssClass="searchLabel">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRefNo" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxes" MaxLength="50">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFrom" runat="server" Text="From:" CssClass="searchLabel">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxes" MaxLength="50">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server" Text="To:" CssClass="searchLabel">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxes" MaxLength="50">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCc" runat="server" Text="Cc:" CssClass="searchLabel">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCc" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxes" MaxLength="50">
    </asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
```

**CSS**

```
.searchTableLabelsCell
{
    font: 12px Verdana;
    width: 300px;      /* it must be 300px */
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: Aqua;
}
.searchLabel
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
    font: 13px Verdana;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: Blue;
    margin-top:15px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}
.textBoxes
{
    width: 120px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    resize: none;
}
```

**Requested align:**

```
    lblrefNo    txtRefNo               <!--CELL WIDTH -->
     lblFrom    txtFrom                <!--CELL WIDTH -->
       lblTo    txtTo                  <!--CELL WIDTH -->
       lblCc    txtCc                  <!--CELL WIDTH -->
```

**IE (bad):**

```
    lblrefNo            txtRefNo lblFrom    txtFrom <!--CELL WIDTH -->
    lblTo    txtTo lblCc    txtCc                   <!--CELL WIDTH -->
```

**Chrome (bad):**

```
    lblrefNo        txtRefNo lblFrom
    txtFrom lblTo
                        txtTo
    lblCc    txtCc
```

Comment: -1, but not every developer was born with css-egg-shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below HTML

Style

```
.searchLabel
{
     display: block;
}
.textBoxes
{
     display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<asp:TableCell ID="tc0" runat="server" CssClass="searchTableLabelsCell">
<div style="display:block; float: left; text-align: right;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblrefNo" runat="server" Text="RefNo:" CssClass="searchLabel">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFrom" runat="server" Text="From:" CssClass="searchLabel">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server" Text="To:" CssClass="searchLabel">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCc" runat="server" Text="Cc:" CssClass="searchLabel">
    </asp:Label>
</div>
<div style="display:block; float: left; margin-left: 10px; text-align: left;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRefNo" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxes" MaxLength="50">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxes" MaxLength="50">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxes" MaxLength="50">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCc" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxes" MaxLength="50">
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>
</asp:TableCell>
```

Comment: Why is it split into 2 div's? Could it be done with 1 div allowing the labels and textboxes to stay together?

Comment: If we will put it in single div then it will look like the last alignment option given in the question (chrome bad) . Because span is not block element. And if you apply display:block to span keeping text box and label together then textbox will appear below the label. I hope you know Label is rendered as span.